# How to change position of Box in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have two `Box`es inside of a `Column`. Both of the Boxes' heights are the same with the Column's (in my code below I set it as `32.dp`) so by default only the first Box is visible, because the 2nd one is pushed below out of the Column's area.

I want to move up the first Box `16dp`, to make the first one's bottom half and the second Box's top half visible at the same time.

My code:

```
@Composable
fun TextCarousel() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(120.dp)
            .height(32.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Red)
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how to `move up` the first Box (in Red) and meantime, `move up` the second Box (in Green), so if `move up 16dp`, I expect it could look like this:

[image]

I've tried adding `.offset(y = (-16).dp)` and `.absoluteOffset(y = (-16).dp)` to the first Box's modifier, but it didn't move up (the document says they are for offsetting the content, but here I want to offset the Box itself).

I've also tried `graphicsLayer`, like this (this is hard-coded):

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(32.dp)
        .width(120.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .background(Color.Red)
        .graphicsLayer {
            translationY = (-16).dp.toPx() // wanted to move up 16dp, but didn't work
        }
)
```

but still no luck.

I hope to find out an approach to update some modifier's value so I can apply it into animation, (in a vertical carousel, the first move up to leave, and the 2nd move up in).

Answer (score 0):

I got an alternative approach, by using AnimatedVisibility.

```
@Composable
fun TextCarousel() {
    var topVisible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    var bottomVisible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        delay(2000)
        topVisible = false
        bottomVisible = true
    })
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(120.dp)
            .height(32.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = topVisible,
            exit = fadeOut() + slideOutVertically { it * -1 }
        ) {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(32.dp)
                    .width(120.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.Red)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello")
            }
        }


        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = bottomVisible,
            enter = fadeIn() + slideInVertically { it }
        ) {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(32.dp)
                    .width(120.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )  {
                Text(text = "World")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Seemed working fine for my carousel usage.

But wanna keep this post open for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I got the answer.

Column, with itself's measure policy, for the code in my question:

```
@Composable
fun TextCarousel() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(120.dp)
            .height(32.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Red)
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

Column has a fixed height 32dp and it has two direct children, the first one's height is 32dp too, this leaves 0dp for the 2nd child(Box).

So that's being said, even though I offset -16dp for the first Box, it still takes up all of the 32dp as height. That also means no matter what offset value we set for the 2nd Box, its height is just 0dp. Therefore it cannot be drawn/shown at all.

Unlikely, if we change `Column` into `Box`, things turn out to be interesting.

With code below:

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(120.dp)
            .height(32.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .offset(y = (-16).dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Red)
        )

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .offset(y = (16).dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .background(Color.Cyan)
                .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                    val size = layoutCoordinates.size.toSize()
                    Log.w("xx", "height = ${size.height}")
                }
        ) {
            Log.w("xx", "minHeight = ${this.minHeight} / maxHeight = ${this.maxHeight}")
        }
    }
```

I got the expected result:

[image]